# Problem in finding next / previous row in mysql

Tags: mysql, unique, max

```
SELECT id ,MAX(status) AS status FROM Mail WHERE 
     status < (SELECT status FROM Mail WHERE id = 1000) 
     GROUP BY status ORDER BY status DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I am using this query to find the previous row of the current row 1000.Here i am getting NULL values if i use the status column which is not unique.where as it gives proper values if i use unique columns.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do? I assume `subject` is a string, why are you trying to get the `MAX` of it? WHen subject is a string, the comparisson with `<` may not give the what you want

Comment: Since the user can sort by subject or status (they are string as you said), i how to find the next and previous rows with that conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m1.id, MAX(m1.status) AS 'status' FROM Mail m1, Mail m2
WHERE m1.status < m2.status AND m2.id = 1000
GROUP BY m1.status ORDER BY m1.status DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks , the problem is "Status" column is not unique so while sorting by status, it skips other rows having same status

Comment: Then change `m1.status < m2.status` to `m1.status <= m2.status`